# Flume - spoolign dir source - ingesting sub directories

Tags: hdfs, flume-ng

I am currently using Flume 1.7 . Configured a spooling directory source. I have enabled recursiveDirectorySearch=true to look in to the sub directories for files.

source.spoolDir=/tmp/test

and under /tmp/test, subdirectories get created with data files  /tmp/test/data1/file.csv , /tmp/test/data2/file2.csv .

I want the exact sub directory structure to be created in the HDFS sink path.

/sink/data1/file.csv
/sink/data2/file2.csv

When i use the %{file} for HDFS sink filepath, i get the complete absolute path, and %{basename} gives me only the file name. I want to extract the sub directory structure from the spooldir source path. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `fileHeader` and `fileHeaderKey` properties and refer to this header variable at your sink configuration to get the absolute path.

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source

Comment: I need a substring out of the absolute path. Is there a way to access that to specify hdfs.path? if my file absolute path is  x/y/z/subdir/file.csv , I only need subdir/file.csv as a hdfs sink path, not the entire absolute path